# While compiling the Tic Tac Toe game program in java a ($ name appended).class is created

Tags: java

While compiling the code of Tic Tac Toe and also while running some codes in java using swing and awt packages. I'm getting a $ appended class file generation, parallel to the ClassName.class file. What may be the reason? Its Whether due to the usage of ActionListeners, it Happens. Usually these kind of creation of .bak file will be generated while doing C programs involving structures.

Support needed regarding these two scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class files containing `$` in their names are nothing but the `inner classes` or `anonymous inner classes` that you might have used inside your top-level class.

For e.g, If you have a class declaration like this: -

```
public class A {
    public class B {
    }
}
```

Then you will have two class files generated: - `A.class` and `A$B.class`. 
This shows the containment of `class B` inside `class A`.

In case of `ActionListener` this is what is happening, in your code.

**UPDATE: -**

If you are using `anonymous inner class`, then also you will get class name with `$` in it: -

```
interface A {
   public void show();
}

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] a) {

        new A() {
            @Override
            public void show() {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        }.show();
    }
}
```

Then the class files generated will be: - `Foo.class` and `Foo$1.class`.

So, if you are using `ActionListener` as anonymous inner class, then also you would get that `$`, in your `class file` name for that `anonymous inner class`.

Comment: Nope but i written I'm just calling through objects of class I never used as a inner class so I have been getting two files, TTTFrame.class and TTTFrame$.class

Comment: @RandMate.. In that case, you might be using an `anonymous inner class`. See updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the Java compiler would compile an inner-class `Bar` of the "main" `Foo` class as Foo$Bar...

That is:

```
class Foo {
   class Bar {
   }
}
```

would create `Foo.class` and `Foo$Bar.class`

Why do you ask? I mean, what's the actual problem?

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: as a beginner just a curiosity. . .